# What is the correct way to load a script with the 'strict-dynamic' CSP directive?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

## Background

The idea of the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) was to tell web-browsers what content to load from where. This means that attackers should not be able to inject their own code if, for example, `'unsafe-inline'` was not explicitly allowed (which is not the best thing to do).

Google also released a [CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/), which is designed to find possible mistakes in your policy. With the default settings, the tool recommends using the `'strict-dynamic'` policy for `'script-src'`. The idea behind it is that you write a loader for whichever JavaScript sourcees you require and forbid everything else.

## The Problem

What is considered the "correct" way to implement such a loader? Should the loader be written yourself (see below for example) or should a tool be used to create such a loader? *(Please note that this question is not asking for a specific tool recommendation)*

### Example

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/path/to/imported/script';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

## Context

My website currently has the following policy:

```
default-src 'none';
img-src 'self';
style-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com 'sha256-bviLPwiqrYk7TOtr5i2eb7I5exfGcGEvVuxmITyg//c=';
script-src https://use.fontawesome.com https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com;
base-uri 'none';
form-action 'none';
frame-ancestors 'none';
```

Google's tool suggested the following:

> Host whitelists can frequently be bypassed. Consider using `'strict-dynamic'` in combination with CSP nonces or hashes.

As such, I want to implement a loader to load these JS frameworks and I want to know how to best approach this issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter. So long as you don't feed the script to the HTML parser via a `document.write()` any JavaScript code that programatically adds a `<script>` as in your sample will be treated exactly the same.

Comment: Also, if you have sufficient control over how your site works, it's better to use a more restrictive policy anyway.

Comment: I don't know if there is anything more restrictive than 'strict-dynamic'. I will edit the question to give more information

Comment: Well `'self'` is pretty restrictive.

Comment: I edited my question to shed more light on my policy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An immediate answer is that as long as the script you're dynamically loading (`/path/to/imported/script`) is hosted in a domain that you've already whitelisted in `script-src`, you don't have to modify your CSP or change your loader -- everything will work as expected.

However, a broader problem is that your `script-src` whitelist includes domains that host Javascript which can be used by an attacker who finds a markup injection bug in your application to bypass your CSP. For example, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com` hosts Angular (`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js`) which can be used by an attacker to convert an HTML injection into arbitrary script execution ([here](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub45542) is a paper about this).

The suggestion in the CSP Evaluator tool is to switch your application to rely on a `script-src` which uses CSP nonces instead of the whitelist. To do this you would need to follow the process outlined at https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html -- basically, make sure that every `<script>` element has a correct `nonce` attribute which changes for every page load, or instead use [CSP3 hashes](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/10/04/csp-for-the-web-we-have/) for static scripts.

Your CSP would then look like:

`... script-src 'nonce-[random-value]' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' https:; ...`

If you use `'strict-dynamic'`, your script loader does not have to change because browsers will automatically trust scripts added to your page via programmatic APIs such as `appendChild()`.

Comment: If **"browsers will automatically trust scripts added to your page via programmatic APIs such as appendChild()"** is true, [such a CSP can no more prevent XSS](https://statuscode.ch/2017/03/CSP-unsafe-eval-and-jquery/). 
 Example from the link: `jQuery(el).html(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substr(1)))`.  Note that `jQuery.globalEval` uses `appendChild()` if the string starts with the `use strict` pragma

Comment: Wayback link for the previous comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20190521015901/https://statuscode.ch/2017/03/CSP-unsafe-eval-and-jquery/

Comment: Re link above - the issue is the trailing slash in the original link - https://statuscode.ch/2017/03/CSP-unsafe-eval-and-jquery works

Comment: A problem here is that a service like cloudflare will inject scripts in to your page. These scripts will always violate because they don't have a nonce, and you cannot white-list them if you use strict-dynamic. Which makes it impossible to let cloudflare inject